# Как узнать текст из input field и записать его в обьекте text

Tags: c#, unity3d

Интересует вопрос , как узнать текст написанный в ходе работы программы на UNITY и перезаписать его же в другую переменную Text .
По итогу мне нужно узнать как записать это в скрипте C#.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То есть вам *просто* нужно взять текст из InputField'a? Мне кажется в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html) это понятно описано.

```
[SerializeField] InputField field; // Ссылка на ваш InputField - указываем в инспекторе
string input_text;

// Получаем текст с помощью поля text в InputField:
input_text = field.text;
```

Если у вас переменная field типа GameObject, то получаете компонент Input Field через `field.GetComponent<InputField>()`, но легче конечно сразу указать через инспектор нужный тип данных.

---

Чтобы записать текст в объект Text:

```
[SerializeField] Text myText; // Ссылка на объект Text

// Присваиваем:
myText.text = input_text;
```

Comment: Если мой ответ был вам полезен, пожалуйста, примите его, поставив галочку:)